# Implementing SCD 2 in Informatica without PK defined on the target

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter, scd

[image]How can we implement SCD 2 in informatica when no PK is defined on target table(oracle)?

Implementing SCD type 2 using Dynamic lkp concept which will tag the incoming row as 0,1,2.
Ive associated the SRC ports to the lookup ports and given the conditioning by specifying the "Update Dynamic Cache Condition" ie MD5(SRC Columns)<>MD5(LKP columns) and enabling the "Output Old Value On Update" with "Insert Else Update" property SET and overriding the LKP sql.

Then in the EXP am flagging the incoming record whether to insert/update using which in Router we will define the grps.

From Router INSERT GRP(FLAG = 'INSERT' or FLAG = 'UPDATE') , 1 target instance for new insert.
UPDATE GRP(FLAG = 'UPDATE') connecting to EXP where i tag the old record status as 'N' and doing the Update Override at the second Target instance since no PK defined am doing this.

Every thing is working fine while i check in debugger mode to check the flow , But when there is an updated record old record gets tagged with status 'N' and new record gets inserted in the first pipeline (first target instance) while old record when it flows from UPDATE grp of router its getting updated with the Status as N and end date am making SYSDATE-1 its working in the Expression but its again getting INSERTED in the second target instance which should get updated with status as N and end date(sysdate-1).But its getting inserted with Status Y and end date with defaukt date Can any one help me to figure whats going wrong here?

Note : in the Session level , for TARGET instance 1 its INSERT and for second instance where update should happen its "UPDATE as UPDATE"

Also tried by keeping the Update Strategy in the second pipe keeping DD_UPDATE and treat source as DATA DRIVEN at the session by specifying the PK at the target designer (Infa level not the db level) but No luck

Comment: Post the mapping structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps**

1. While performing SCD, you first have to identity the history records and you have to 
   first update the history records and then insert the new records
2. You have to use **target load plan** and set, first your update flow should apply and then insert operation should happen. You will have target load plan in mapping tab

[image]

3. In session task, in properties tab, change Treat source row as to Data driven

[image]

Comment: Could you plz share the Mapping Structure (note that there is no PK defined on the target table) which your are highlighting too that would be helpful

Comment: Your mapping screen shot shows there are primary keys in your target table

Comment: You have to use data driven options in session level. As mentioned in the second screen shot. Also can you show what expression are you using in update strategy

Comment: I have defined the PKs at the Target designer level not at the db level so that i can use update strategy for updating the old records by keeping the DATA DRIVEV option at the session level then also its getting insert rather than updating , In Update strategy its DD_UPDATE

Comment: Did use target load plan option?

Comment: I havent alter the target load plan , by default its first pipeline (first target instance for New inserts) and then the second instance for update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215088/discussion-between-jim-macaulay-and-bastian).